# Container stuck at creating in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Am trying to create a deployment for exhibitor, when i execute the kubectl apply command container stuck at creating status. When i describe it, am getting the below error.

Note:- For other pod am not getting any issue and am using flannel network.

> Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to set up sandbox container "0d459281ccc36f" network for pod "exhibitor-6fdcbdf9c-d7t6v": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "exhibitor-6fdcbdf9c-d7t6v_default" network: error getting ClusterInformation: Get https://[10.96.0.1]:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes"), failed to clean up sandbox container "0d422ffb519a9a9be4dfbd9c6b235505f5a0e8181ccc36f" network for pod "exhibitor-6fdcb9c-dt6v": networkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod "exhibitor-6fdcbc-t6v_default" network: error getting ClusterInformation: Get https://[10.96.0.1]:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")]

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: exhibitor
  name: exhibitor
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 2147483647
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2147483647
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: exhibitor
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: exhibitor
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: netflixoss/exhibitor:1.5.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: exhibitor
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2888
          hostPort: 2888
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 2181
          hostPort: 2181
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 3888
          hostPort: 3888
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
#      nodeSelector:
#        disktype: master
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status: {}
```

```html
When i execute the  kubectl get pods -n kube-system geeting the below things.

NAME                                        READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-66bff467f8-q2j55                    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          2d13h
coredns-66bff467f8-w2l7z                    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          2d13h
etcd-ip-172-16-176-201                      1/1     Running             2          2d13h
kube-apiserver-ip-172-16-176-201            1/1     Running             2          2d13h
kube-controller-manager-ip-172-16-176-201   1/1     Running             2          2d13h
kube-proxy-8bfvg                            1/1     Running             2          2d13h
kube-proxy-lwrd8                            1/1     Running             2          2d13h
kube-proxy-r6w9m                            1/1     Running             2          2d13h
kube-scheduler-ip-172-16-176-201            1/1     Running             2          2d13h
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please can you share more information about this Kubernetes you are using?  Is it Minikube or some flavour from a cloud provider (Like GKE, for example).

Initially the error looks quite clear, you have a certificate signed by an unknown authority.  How did you get credentials for the cluster?  This may vary from provider to provider.

Comment: are you switching between different cni such as flannel and calico? provide output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Comment: Arghya tnx for the quick responce. Am not switching between the n/w's. I have added the output of  kubectl get pods -n kube-system in the question. I found core dns is not getting created and after descriing it seeing this one "  Normal  SandboxChanged  73s (x780 over 171m)  kubelet, ip-172-16-200-201  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created. 
"

Comment: have you installed a cni plugin? what and how you have installed it?

Comment: Yeah i have install flannel and followed this document from github for installing "https://github.com/coreos/flannel"

Comment: Yeah Arghya, thanks a lot. It's resolved my issue, container is created and pod is running successfully. :)